# Get list of row from a DataSet

Tags: c#, dataset

I have this dataset like this:

[image]

How can I get the string "TITLE" and "SUMMARY"?

I have this code:

```
string path = @"C:\Users\Pichau\Downloads\teste\data.xml";
XmlDocument x = new XmlDocument();
x.Load(path);
StringReader stream = new StringReader(x.InnerXml);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml(stream);

foreach (var i in ds.Tables["col"].Columns)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i.ToString());
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

But with this code I get the following output:

```
name
type
col_Text
row_Id
```

I want to access the value of "TITLE" in the "name" column

Answer (score 0):

You will need to find the `DataRow` that corresponds to your `TITLE` and `SUMMARY` rows, and then access the values of the appropriate columns.

Try this:

```
foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables["col"].Rows) {
   if (row["name"] == "TITLE") {
      Console.WriteLine(row["col_Text"]);
   }
}
```

Comment: Nothing appears on the console, it does not pass if